# Not able to figure out error in this code?

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
CREATE TABLE Inventory 
(
    InventoryNumber INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductCode VARCHAR(10),
    ColorCode VARCHAR(10),
    Size VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Price DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    QuantityOnHand INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Inventory_Size CHECK (Size IN ('S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL')),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Inventory_Price CHECK (Price <= 9999.99),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Inventory_QuantityOnHand CHECK (QuantityOnHand >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Inventory_Product FOREIGN KEY (ProductCode) REFERENCES Product(ProductCode),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Inventory_Color FOREIGN KEY (ColorCode) REFERENCES Color(ColorCode),
    UNIQUE (ProductCode, ColorCode, Size)
);
```

> Error report
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Comment: [Oracle 23c](https://dbfiddle.uk/4bWSnamk) gives a more descriptive error: ORA-03050: invalid identifier: "SIZE" is a reserved word. Change the name of that column. (Or make it a quoted identifier, but... don't do that.)

Answer (score 2):

`SIZE` is a [reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html#GUID-55C49D1E-BE08-4C50-A9DD-8593EB925612) and cannot be used as an unquoted identifier.

Either use a different identifier:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Inventory (
    InventoryNumber INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductCode,
    ColorCode,
    ItemSize        VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    Price           DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    QuantityOnHand  INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Inventory_Size CHECK (ItemSize IN ('S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL')),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Inventory_Price CHECK (Price <= 9999.99),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Inventory_QuantityOnHand CHECK (QuantityOnHand >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Inventory_Product FOREIGN KEY (ProductCode) REFERENCES Product(ProductCode),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Inventory_Color FOREIGN KEY (ColorCode) REFERENCES Color(ColorCode),
    UNIQUE (ProductCode, ColorCode, ItemSize)
);
```

or use a quoted identifier (although that is not considered good practice as you would have to use a quoted identifier everywhere the column is used):

```sql
CREATE TABLE Inventory (
    InventoryNumber INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductCode,
    ColorCode,
    "Size"          VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
    Price           DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    QuantityOnHand  INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Inventory_Size CHECK ("Size" IN ('S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL')),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Inventory_Price CHECK (Price <= 9999.99),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Inventory_QuantityOnHand CHECK (QuantityOnHand >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Inventory_Product FOREIGN KEY (ProductCode) REFERENCES Product(ProductCode),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Inventory_Color FOREIGN KEY (ColorCode) REFERENCES Color(ColorCode),
    UNIQUE (ProductCode, ColorCode, "Size")
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z5xKsVN5)